# .NET 5 RC1 API Controller constructor issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, blazor-webassembly, .net-5

I am working moving a Blazor WebAssembly project (Net Core 3.1) over to .NET 5 RC1 but I am having issues with a controller.
This code:

```
        [Authorize]
        [Route("[controller]")]
        [ApiController]
        public class ApplicationUserController : ControllerBase
        {
            private readonly RGDbContext _context;
            // Create a field to store the mapper object
            private readonly IMapper _mapper;
            private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
            private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
            // Field for DBContext

            // Assign the object in the constructor for dependency injection
            public ApplicationUserController(RGDbContext context, IMapper mapper, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
            {
                _context = context;
                _mapper = mapper;
                _userManager = userManager;
                _signInManager = signInManager;
            }
```

Works fine under Core 3.1, but now is crashing out as soon as the controller is invoked - sorry I cant be more specific than that, but there is no exception, the calling blazor app just gets a 500 error, and no breakpoints are hit in the controller.

If I comment out the constructor code so I effectively just have:

```
                public ApplicationUserController()
            {
            }
```

It works, at least to the extent that I can successfully call in to the controller and hit a break point, and return 'stuff' - I pasted in the 'WeatherController' template code...

My question is should the dependency injection still work in .NET 5  - see that there is this:

[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/5.0.0-rc.1.20451.14)

But that looks like something for .Net Framework, as it lists .NET Framework 4.6.1 as one of its dependencies.

Besides, Dependency injection IS working in my project, I use it in the Startup.Cs to pass user and role managers to my config code...

```
                public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env,
                     UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
            {
```

Do controllers behave differently, do I have to go back to a more .Net Framework centric way of initialising/passing these objects, is it broken (fully aware that this is bleeding edge), or am I just barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Have you tried doing what you said "works", adding an empty constructor, and then adding back one dependency at a time until it breaks? Perhaps this might yield some insight into what might be wrong.

Comment: Yes, I did ... it fell over at the first one.. I am just trying an experiment - scaffolding a new controller with CRUD so it uses the DB context. Weirdly it added sqlite as a dependency (not sure why - yet) but the code it creates does use DI for the context so I tried it again with just the context and the mapper enabled and it has failed again. I am going to try and call the scaffolded controller - see what happens...

Comment: Ok, I found my issue and am putting it out here anyway in case someone else has it. I had not correctly set up the AutoMapper in the project. That said, there was no indication in terms of the intellisense that there was any issue either and it all built fine. So 'blaming the tools' ? yes, but as I said before I do realise I am at the bleeding edge, so I don't blame anyone.